# fadeIn a text via CSS content method on Hover

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to **fadeIn** a text on an element via **CSS content method** but it doesn't seem to be working. my code is as shown below. Is this not possible or can it be achieved.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="share-box">
   <i class="fa fa-rss"></i>
 </div><!-- End Share Box -->
```

**CSS**

```
#share-box {
float: right;
height: 100px;
font-size: 72px;
width: 80px;
color: #fff;
font-weight: lighter;
padding-top: 15px;
background-color: #E18728;
padding-left: 25px;
cursor: pointer;
        }

#share-box:before {
content: 'RSS';
position: absolute;
font-size: 24px;
padding: 70px 0 0 15px;
display: none;
    }
```

**Script**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 

 $("#share-box").mouseover(function(){

 $("#share-box:before").stop().fadeIn();

  });



 $("#share-box").mouseout(function(){

 $("#share-box:before").stop().fadeOut('slow');

  });

});
```

[Link to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sleek/Xf94H/8/)

Comment: Could you please share fiddle if possible?

Comment: Why not just use a `:hover` selector and transition the opacity? No JavaScript required

Comment: mouseout jquery start with "i" instead "$". Is it typo or you have the code like this.

Comment: :before is not a dom element. so jquery will not work on :before.

Comment: You cannot select pseudo-elements with JS.JQ as they are not in the DOM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented by @Phil, You could just use the `:hover` pseudo-class along with `transition` to achieve that. JS not required really.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/z3A33/***

```
#share-box:before {
    ...
    opacity: 0; /* use opacity to get it working with transition */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* use transition to get fading effect */
    transition: all 1s; /* use standards after vendor prefixes */
}
#share-box:hover::before {
    opacity: 1; /* change opacity on hover */
}
```

*Note*: You need something like `opacity` to get the transition working. Transitions won't work with `display`.